# HALACHICALY Is it ok to download YouTube videos?

Tags: internet, gezel-stealing

This question has confounded me for some time. On the one hand, from the research I've done, it's definitely against the terms of service which you agree to. On the other, everything I've read on the matter noted that YouTube has expressed no desire yet to penalise this behavior, but does shut down certain 3rd party sites built to do this. Implying from this they are obviously aware that people do this, (if that makes any difference, not sure it does), the question still becomes a more foggy one - is it an act of stealing? You're not depriving anyone of any money, other than the potential funds they *would have* gotten from your view, but there's no act of stealing. I'm of course talking from complete ignorance, so if anyone could shed some light on the matter, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I feel like this was asked before

Comment: @Kazibácsi I'm not sure it's a duplicate because there are other things to download from YouTube, not just music. Classes, lectures, etc. I don't know if those are all necessarily comparable.

Comment: @Harel13 From a copyright law perspective they're all intellectual property of someone, exactly like music.

Comment: I don't feel this question should have been closed. The earlier question was about pirated music that a person is now getting for free. In this case, the issue is a video that is already available for free. How is it stealing? Or to put it another way, let's say I'm watching a youtube video on my computer. That information is currently playing on my computer. Am I allowed to record it as it plays? (or streaming music). I cannot see why this would be considered stealing. Is it stealing to record a song that's playing on the radio?